# Observer for each method of a class

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I want to keep observer for each method in java i.e. if any of method is called, i should be notified. or if any of member variable is updated, i should be notified. Is there any java framework to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). This framework allows you to add hooks for method invocations and field updates.

Comment: You can also monitor get/set fields, but not locals http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html

Comment: Aha, nice I didn't know that :-)